# Convert discrete points to continuous function

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to get a continuous function from a series of points.

Let's say my discrete points are :

```
df_demand <- structure(list(x = c(0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.9, 1), y = c(1, 0.5, 0.2, 
0.01, 0.01)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to create a continuous function in order to predict y as a function of a specific x (e.g. `x = 0.3`).

What I did until now was to approximate this function using a polynomial model :

```
model <- glm(y ~ poly(x,3), data = df_demand)

data.frame(x = seq(0,1,length = 1000)) %>% 
  mutate(pred=predict(model, .)) %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = pred))+
  geom_point(data = df_demand, aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red")
```

[image: Polynomial model to fit discrete points]

But the issue with this method is it does not generalize well depending on my input.

I am looking for a function like a continuous moving average that I can call as a function (`y = moving_average(x)`), but despite what I've read so far, I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Can you show an example of when it doesn't work well?

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "smoother"  function, e.g., `library(mgcv); 
model <- gam(y ~ s(x, k = 4), data = df_demand)`. If you have more data points, you don't need to set `k`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. This is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `splinefun`:

```
f <- splinefun(df_demand$x,df_demand$y)
plot(f)
points(df_demand$x,df_demand$y)
```

[image: Spline]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Especially with parameter `method = "hyman"`. Thanks !